# Read URL parameter in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, get

My Jquery mobile form with the list view has the below format.

```
<div data-role="page" id="arealistpage">

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Area</h1>
        <a href="../MenuePages/Dictionaries.aspx" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l' rel="external">Back</a>   <!-- your button to go back to index.php#user page -->
   <a href="AddArea.aspx" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="d" style="float:left;"  rel="external" data-transition="slide">Add</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">  
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c"  data-filter="true" id="areaList" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
  <li><a href="#dialog?AreaNo=1" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Test</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
    </ul>

    </div><!-- /content -->

     <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">

            <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>

               <li><a href="" data-role="tab" data-icon="arrow-u" class="returnTopAction">Top</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


        <!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
<div data-role="page" id="dialog">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Options</h1>
  </div>   

 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false"
                data-theme="c">
               <%-- <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Options</li>--%>
                <li data-icon="false"><a>Edit</a></li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a>Delete</a></li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a>...</a></li>
            </ul>   
</div>
```

i need to open the "dialog" div as a dialog on listview row click and
read the url parameter from the dialog. i need to get the AreaNo
parameter from the url

tag and pass it to the Edit URL in open
dialog. Currently i can not open the dialog and it's not working.
please help and sorry for the bad english

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, I created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your html as below

```
<div data-role="page" id="arealistpage">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1>Area</h1>
 <a href="../MenuePages/Dictionaries.aspx" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back'
        data-icon='arrow-l' rel="external">Back</a> 
        <!-- your button to go back
        to index.php#user page --> <a href="AddArea.aspx" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="d"
        style="float:left;" rel="external" data-transition="slide">Add</a>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="primaryList">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-filter="true"
            id="areaList" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" id='dialogListView'>
                <li><a href="#dialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-areano="1">Test</a>

                    <a
                    class="deleteMe"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" data-role="tab" data-icon="arrow-u" class="returnTopAction">Top</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
</div>
<!-- Dialog Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1>Options</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="c">
            <!-- <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Options</li>-->
            <li data-icon="false"><a>Edit</a>

            </li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a>Delete</a>

            </li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a>...</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and added a click event for the list as below

```
$('div[id="primaryList"] ul[data-role="listview"] a').live("click", function () {
    var areaNo = $(this).data("areano");
    sessionStorage.areaNo = areaNo;
    alert("area no : " + sessionStorage.areaNo);
});
```

now you can access the area code throughout your application using the session storage variable `sessionStorage.areaNo`.  Read more about [sessionStorage here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/).

here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9CctZ/7/